# Loop until non blank column

Tags: excel, vba

Needed to write code for copy paste date in single column.

by means of that there are n numbers of columns and needed to paste those in single column.

code that i tried but not working well

```
    Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B4:B12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D4:D12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("G3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F4:F8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H4:H10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B4:C12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("D4:E12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("D11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("F4:G8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("D20").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("H4:I10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("D25").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

i am posting image to show you which type of input i have and what type of output i needed. please help me to crack it ...Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's not for us to write code for you or teach you from scratch. There are plenty of tutorials on the web to help you learn the basics of VB development and they will all teach you how to write loops of various kinds. You need to do your research, make your best attempt to write the code you need and then, if it doesn't work, post a question explaining what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it, and what happens when you try. If you haven't tried, you haven't encountered and issue.

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried and explain how it did not meet expectations.

Comment: vb.net or VBA? Two different things. While there is a lot wrong with your code, most essential, the criteria for you loop, won't work. `Do until i < 6`? Do you know that this reads, "Loop untill my i variable holds a value that is smaller than 6"? Effectively never going to run your code. I would go with: Loop C3,E3 and G3, use offset, resize to create an array of values and do a value transfer instead of copy-paste. Avoid selecting cells/sheets as it's slow, redundant and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. And welcome to VBA. Please study the code example below. it will do what you described.

```
Option Explicit                         ' always use this statement

Sub LoopColumns()

    ' always identify and declare your worksheets
    Dim WsS As Worksheet                ' Source sheet
    Dim WsD As Worksheet                ' Destination sheet
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Dim C As Long                       ' column number
    Dim Rld As Long                     ' last row in WsD

    Set WsS = ActiveSheet               ' better identify the sheet by name
    Set WsS = Worksheets("Sheet1")      ' this is the sheet I used
    Set WsD = Worksheets("Sheet5")      ' better give the sheet a descriptive name

    For C = 1 To 6 Step 2               ' select columns 1, 3 and 5 in turn
        ' specify the range starting in row 4 of the looped column
        '   and end at the end of that column, offset by 1
        Set CopyRange = WsS.Range(WsS.Cells(4, C), _
                                  WsS.Cells(WsS.Rows.Count, C).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))

        ' determine the row below the last used row in WsD
        Rld = WsD.Cells(WsD.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If Rld < 3 Then Rld = 3         ' start from row 3 3
        ' paste to column A below the last used row
        CopyRange.Copy Destination:=WsD.Cells(Rld, "A")
    Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: hey brother Thank a lot for your effort! but still it is not getting my solution. i just recorded a macro .can u look and provide me with loop for n number of column?

Answer (score 0):

Change the ranges and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowCol As Long, LastRowOut As Long, i As Long, StartColumn As Long, Endcolumn As Long

    StartColumn = 2
    Endcolumn = 6

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For i = StartColumn To Endcolumn Step 2

            LastRowCol = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

            LastRowOut = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

            .Range(.Cells(4, i), .Cells(LastRowCol, i + 1)).Copy .Range("J" & LastRowOut + 1)

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]